# Removing last 4 characters from multiple columns in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I am new to programming/coding and new to RStudio.

I am working with a dataset in RStudio, `'ethica_surveys'`. Three columns within my dataset are contain data that is date, time, time zone - i.e., `'2018-06-15 11:49:22 CST'`. I want to remove the CST from each of these columns.

I first tried this :

```
str_sub(ethica_surveys$schedule_time,1,str_length(ethica_surveys$schedule_time)-4)
```

It worked, but only showed me the newly edited column in my console, my dataset did not change.

I then tried:

```
ethica_surveys <- str_sub(ethica_surveys$schedule_time,1,str_length(ethica_surveys$schedule_time)-4)
```

This changed the column in my dataset, but also seemed to erase all the other columns in the dataset.

I want to erase the CST (last 4 characters) in each of these three columns: schedule_time, issued_time, and response_time. I want this change to be reflected in my dataset, without erasing the other columns within the dataset. Can anyone advise as to how this could be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the output of your transformation to your variable:

`ethica_surveys$schedule_time <- str_sub(ethica_surveys$schedule_time,1,str_length(ethica_surveys$schedule_time)-4)`